# centralManager(_:didConnect:) sometimes not getting caled

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I want to build an iOS App, which connects every minute with a BLE peripheral to retrieve a specific characteristic. In most cases this works very well, but after a few hours the CBPeripheral's state gets stucked at `.connecting` sometimes, if I try to connect again.

I tried to observe that behavior with a Bluetooth sniffer:

```
1,010,604   38  ADV_IND         (pub)   0x000000000159  24  42   00:00:00.000665    23.02.2017 02:55:22.715507  

1,010,605   38  CONNECT_IND (rand)  0x000000000901  (pub)   0x000000000159  34  52   00:00:00.000424    23.02.2017 02:55:22.715931
```

As you can see, the peripheral sends out the advertising and my iPhone answers with the connect indication directly. At this point the CPPeripheral's state stuck at `.connecting` and `centralManager(_:didConnect:)` is not getting called.

At the moment I just retry to connect to the peripheral and the 4th or 5th attempt is working. But why does that happen? I can't recognize a pattern in this strange behavior.

Comment: Do you connect and disconnect each minute or try to stay connected?

Comment: I disconnect every time.

Comment: Why do you do that?  Why not stay connected?

Comment: It's a demand from the peripheral producer. They want to save energy this way. Apple don't like this attempt, right?

Comment: I would have thought that continually connecting and disconnecting would use more energy than simply maintaining a connection and reading the value periodically.